# insert rows via a python generator using snowflake executemany function

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I have a snowflake table and I am using the [Snowflake Python Connector](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python) to insert value into it. Since I have a lot of data I am using a python generator object to insert value into my table.

```
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(...)
with conn.cursor() as write_cur:
    write_cur.executemany("INSERT INTO TABLE_1 VALUES (%s, %s)",
                          generator_data)
```

but this seems to throw an error that generator has no attribute len() .
Is there anyway I can use an iterator to insert values into a snowflake table.

Comment: can u pls add your generator_data code

Comment: It will be a big code, you can consider something like this for now ((x,y) for x,y in zip(random.sample(range(1, 10000000), 30000000),random.sample(range(1, 10000000), 30000000)))

Comment: `executemany` function expecting an iterable that has a length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible don't do this - individual inserts are slow.

Instead batch collect all the values to insert, and then in one `INSERT` bring in all the rows.

But let's talk about the code in the question: There's nothing to iterate through. For `cursor()` to iterate, first you need results out of somewhere to iterate through.